# Image won't show

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

When `bigImg` becomes an image it does show, but when `sprites[dir]` becomes an image it doesn't show.
When running, I drew a small box to show where the sprite will be and there is nothing inside it.

```
 public void getSprite(){
    BufferedImage bigImg = null;
    try {
        bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Pacman.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("hey");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // The above line throws an checked IOException which must be caught.

    final int width = 7;
    final int height = 7;
    final int rows = 4;
    final int cols = 3;
    BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];
    System.out.println(bigImg.getHeight() + "," + bigImg.getWidth());
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            sprites[(i * cols) + j] = bigImg.getSubimage(
                j * width,
                i * height,
                width,
                height
            );
        }
    } 
    //image = bigImg;
}

 public void setSprite (int direction){
    System.out.println("HEY");
    System.out.println(sprites[1].getHeight());
    image = sprites[direction];
}
```

Comment: Is the exception thrown?

Comment: no the exception is not thrown...

Comment: do you ever call `getSprite()`?

Comment: pacman.png is located at the root directory of the project, it does work without being split so thats not the problem.

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: getSprite is called when the object is created

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.